# IE8 is breaking my AJAX... FF is fine

Tags: javascript, ajax, firefox, internet-explorer-8

Feeling very proud of myself after creating a form with an AJAX submit, I test it in IE8 and get "Message: 'quantity' is undefined". I've read that it could be something to do with the fact that earlier versions of IE used ActiveX for AJAX requests, but I'm very new to JS and have no real understanding of the problem, let alone the ability to implement a fix.

Here's my code:

```
var time_variable;

function getXMLObject()  //XML OBJECT
{
  var xmlHttp = false;
   try {
     xmlHttp = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP")  // For Old Microsoft Browsers
   }
   catch (e) {
     try {
       xmlHttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")  // For Microsoft IE 6.0+
     }
     catch (e2) {
       xmlHttp = false   // No Browser accepts the XMLHTTP Object then false
     }
   }
   if (!xmlHttp && typeof XMLHttpRequest != 'undefined') {
     xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();        //For Mozilla, Opera Browsers
   }
   return xmlHttp;  // Mandatory Statement returning the ajax object created
}

var xmlhttp = new getXMLObject();   //xmlhttp holds the ajax object

function ajaxFunction() {
  var getdate = new Date();  //Used to prevent caching during ajax call
  if(xmlhttp) { 
    var txtname = document.getElementById("txtname");
    xmlhttp.open("POST","slots.php",true); //calling     testing.php using POST method
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange  = handleServerResponse;
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
    xmlhttp.send("quantity=" + quantity.value + "&price=" + price.value + "&slot=" +         slot.value + "&store=" + store.value); //Posting txtname to PHP File


  }
}

function handleServerResponse() {
   if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4) {
     if(xmlhttp.status == 200) {
       document.getElementById("message").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText; //Update the     HTML Form element 
     }
     else {
        alert("Error during AJAX call. Please try again");
     }
   }
}
```

Comment: Looks like IE were not able to find quantity.
Where did it came from?

Comment: Yes, I think we need to see a bit more code - where is 'quantity' defined? Is it a global variable?

Comment: Quantity is just a form field:

<input type="text" name="quantity" id="quantity" onFocus="clearForm()" />
<input type="text" name="price" id="price" />

 <tr>
  <td>Slot</td>
  <td><input type="text" name="slot" id="slot" />
    <input name="store" type="hidden" id="store" value="barnstaple"></td>
 </tr> 


 <tr>
  <td colspan="2"><input type="button" value="Add" onClick="ajaxFunction();" /></td>
 </tr> 
</table>
<div id="message" name="message"></div> 
</form>

Comment: In my opinion you really should use a JavaScript Framework like jQuery or mootools to leverage the browsers exceptions. Let them deal with all the fancy browsers flavors and keep yourself focused on your App Logic.

Comment: I don't necessarily agree with that Frankie - if you're learning, I think it's good to know what's going on under the hood, in case you're ever in a situation where you can't rely on jQuery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your last comment on your question, I suspect you are not defining 'quantity' anywhere and assuming that it will reference the form field. Try this:

```
if(xmlhttp) { 
    var txtname = document.getElementById("txtname");
    var quantity = document.getElementById("quantity");
    var price = document.getElementById("price");
    var store = document.getElementById("store");
    xmlhttp.open("POST","slots.php",true); //calling     testing.php using POST method
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange  = handleServerResponse;
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
    xmlhttp.send("quantity=" + quantity.value + "&price=" + price.value + "&slot=" +               slot.value + "&store=" + store.value); //Posting txtname to PHP File
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If quantity is a form field you need to get it using getElementById before using it just like you did with txtname:

```
var quantity = document.getElementById("quantity");
```

You cant use it directly from the form.